# How to find a fair index's letter in an String array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to find duplicated letter in the same position and return the value [duplicated first arr, duplicated  second arr, duplicated index position]

Here is an example.
String [] arr = ["cat","hat","foo"]
arr[0] = "cat" and arr[1] = "hat" has same letter "t" on index 2.
so you can return 0,1,2 ( duplicated first arr,duplicated second arr, duplicated index position)

I try to make below, I can't do anymore..

```
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        String s = arr[i];
        char word = s.charAt(s);
      for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length(); j++){
        
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private String findFirstFairIndex(String[] arr) {
    String firstString, secondString;
    int firstIndex, secondIndex, compareIndex;

    for (firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < arr.length - 1; firstIndex++) {
        firstString = arr[firstIndex];

        for (secondIndex = firstIndex + 1; secondIndex < arr.length; secondIndex++) {
            secondString = arr[secondIndex];

            for (compareIndex = 0; compareIndex < firstString.length(); compareIndex++) {

                if (firstString.charAt(compareIndex) == secondString.charAt(compareIndex)) {
                    return String.format("[%d,%d,%d]", firstIndex, secondIndex, compareIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement a method say `int getMatchingIndex(string1, string2)` which returns a valid index in case a match is found or return -1 in case no match is found.
2. Iterate over the list/array, keep the index stored in some temporary variable, say `firstArrayIndex`
3. For each item from Step 2, iterate over the whole list (if that is the intention) and keep the index stored in some temporary variable, say `secondArrayIndex`
4. Invoke `int index = getMatchingIndex(firstItem, secondItem)`, if `index > -1`, save the result like `firstArrayIndex, secondArrayIndex, index` and keep iterative or return (as per the requirement)

**Pseudo Code: (Not exactly but mix of code & pseudocode)**

```
int getMatchingIndex(string1, string2) {
     index = -1
     i = 0
     loop until i < string1.length && i < string2.length
          if string1[i] == string2[i]
              index = i
              break
          return index;
}

loop arr with index as idx1
     index1 = idx1
     loop arr with index as idx2
         index2 = idx2
         matchedIndex = getMatchingIndex(arr[idx1], arr[idx2]
         if matchedIndex > -1
              save or return (idx1, idx2, matchedIndex)
```